# Grouping similar times together

Tags: r, datetime, grouping

I have a data frame with systolic blood pressure and date/time. The readings were sometimes taken within minutes of each other, sometimes not. An example is below:

```
library(tidyverse)

date_time <- c("Jan 29 2020 13:46:08" , 
              "Jan 29 2020 13:42:53" , 
              "Jan 29 2020 12:13:27" ,
              "Jan 29 2020 12:11:19" , 
              "Jan 29 2020 12:09:21" , 
              "Jan 28 2020 12:22:26" , 
              "Jan 27 2020 8:22:20")

systol <- c(132  , 132  , 118  , 115  , 110 , 148 , 120)

df <- data.frame(date_time , systol) %>%
  mutate(dtetime = lubridate::mdy_hms(date_time)
```

I want to group the systolic readings taken near to each other in time--arbitrarily, with the last reading taken within 10 minutes of the first reading in any group--and average the readings (and ideally average the date/time of the reading as well). I've tried thinking it through using lag and lead functions and then group_by, and could not devise a way to do that if there are not 2 readings in a group. I'm most familiar with the tidyverse so prefer that approach but am interested in any way of doing this. I'm relatively new to R. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 0):

here's an approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

> dt[, .(mean_value = mean(systol)), by = .(mean_time = lubridate::round_date(x = dtetime, unit = '10 min'))]
             mean_time mean_value
1: 2020-01-29 13:50:00   132.0000
2: 2020-01-29 13:40:00   132.0000
3: 2020-01-29 12:10:00   114.3333
4: 2020-01-28 12:20:00   148.0000
5: 2020-01-27 08:20:00   120.0000
```

I'm using `round_date`, which, as the name suggests, rounds time to the nearest 10 min, you could also look at `floor_date` or other options to get your desired output.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. In dt, rows 1 and 2 are in separate groups, because row 1 of df is rounded up from 13:46 to 13:50, and row 2 is rounded down from 13:42 to 13:40--and they should be in the same group since they are within a 10-minute span.

Comment: How do you define the "anchor" point for time e.g. if you have three times (showing minutes only): 9, 11, 13, 20, 23 and you chooses 13 as your time anchor, all entries will be included in the avg. However, if you choose 20, "9" will be excluded since it's outside of the 10 min range on either side. Or do you want to preserve the original time stamps and original measurement and also get a new measurement equal to the avg. of anything within 10 min of said observation? Can you share a larger example and the exact outcome you want?

Comment: Looking at df as an example, this is the result I would want:
group 1: rows 1 and 2
group2: rows 3, 4, 5
group3: row 6
group 4: row 7
The object is to average readings that were taken close to each other in time, since they can be seen as clustered. The criterion for "close in time" is readings that are all taken within 10 minutes--i.e,. the last reading in any group has to be within 10 minutes of the first reading in that group. Groups can have any number of readings, as long as the group meets the criterion. I believe df shows the complexity of the problem. Does that clarify?

Comment: PS. Perhaps it would help to say these are shown as readings for one person over tine.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` basically. After `order`ing the readings increasingly, make a vector of differences from the first reading,

```
d <- d[order(d$dtetime), ]  ## order readings increasingly
dff <- with(d, as.numeric(dtetime) - as.numeric(dtetime)[1])  ## calc. diff from 1st reading
```

allowing to create 10 min bins (in seconds).

```
bins <- seq(min(dff), max(dff)*1.24, 10 * 60)  ## 10 min bins
```

Now we can `cut` at these bins to divide into groups and calculating `mean`s of time and systol while `aggregate`ing along them.

```
d$group <- cut(dff, breaks=bins, include.lowest=TRUE)
res <- aggregate(cbind(dtetime, systol) ~ group, d, mean)[-1]
res$dtetime <- as.POSIXct(res$dtetime, origin="1970-01-01")  ## converting back to POSIX 
res
#               dtetime systol
# 1 2020-01-27 08:22:20  120.0
# 2 2020-01-28 12:22:26  148.0
# 3 2020-01-29 12:10:20  112.5
# 4 2020-01-29 12:13:27  118.0
# 5 2020-01-29 13:44:30  132.0
```

---

*Data:*

```
date_time <- c("Jan 29 2020 13:46:08", "Jan 29 2020 13:42:53", "Jan 29 2020 12:13:27", 
               "Jan 29 2020 12:11:19", "Jan 29 2020 12:09:21", "Jan 28 2020 12:22:26", 
               "Jan 27 2020 8:22:20")
systol <- c(132, 132, 118, 115, 110, 148, 120)
d <- data.frame(dtetime=strptime(date_time, format="%b %e %Y %H:%M:%S") , systol)
```